# Making a Socket io singleton class to be used in any file

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I need access to the `io` module in multiple files in my project so I can emit some messages. So for that I decided to create a singleton class to handle the `io` object so i can import the class anywhere and use the `io` object.

When I comment out all the middleware, it works. But I don't want that, I want the connection to be only made when the user is logged in.

here's my `socketClass.js`

```js
const session = require('express-session');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const passport = require('passport');


class SocketManager{
    constructor() {
        this.io = null;
    }

    start(server) {
        this.io = new Server(server);

        // convert a connect middleware to a Socket.IO middleware
        const wrap = middleware => (socket, next) => middleware(socket.request, {}, next);

        const sessionMiddleware = session({
            secret: 'MySecrectKey',
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true
        });
        this.io.use(wrap(sessionMiddleware));
        this.io.use(wrap(passport.initialize()));
        this.io.use(wrap(passport.session()));

        this.io.use((socket, next) => {
            if (socket.request.user) {
                next();
            } else {
                next(new Error('unauthorized'))
            }
        });
    }

    get() {
        return this.io;
    }

}

module.exports = new SocketManager();
```

Here's my `app.js`

```js
...
const SocketManager = require('./socketClass');
const server = http.createServer(app);
SocketManager.start(server);
const io = SocketManager.get();

io.on('connect', async (socket) => {
    console.log(`new connection ${socket.id}`);
    socket.on('whoami', (cb) => {
        cb(socket.request.user ? socket.request.user.username : '');
    });
});
```

The `io.on('connect')` wont console.log anything on a new connection. What is the problem here?

Comment: It should print when you connect with a client. So does your client successfuly connect or do you get any errors?

Comment: It doesn't print anything. I dont get any errors as well.

Comment: Can you also share the code you use on the client side? Does it emit connected event?

Comment: It doesn't even console log on the server side. and No It doesn't emit anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be because of "**async (socket)**". Here is how I do it as simply as possible !

I created a separate file (module):

**socket.js:**

```
let io;

module.exports = {
  init: httpServer => {
    io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);
    return io;
  },
  getIO: () => {
    if (!io) {
      throw new Error('Socket.io not initialized!');
    }
    return io;
  }
};
```

Then, in my app.js:

```
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(8080);
const io = require('./socket').init(server);
    io.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log('Client connected');
    });
```

Comment: Where to I set the Middleware?

Comment: which middleware ?

Comment: Look at my `start(server)` function.

Comment: Should be in my init function !

Comment: I saw this solution on another stackoverflow question and tried it as well but it doesn't work with the middleware. I've updated the question.